# how to make war file take up less memory

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, out-of-memory, war

I need help on how to decrease the memory usage of my web app. so I can fit more into my webserver.

so I'm building a java web app with JSF 2.0 developing in eclipse helios and running on an Apache tomcat Server. And I have a dedicated virtual server with a tomcat aswell where I deploy these war files. the webApp is about 35MB in size ( it has a lot of jars and such) but when I deploy it to my tomcat webserver, I can see it takes about 300MB of RAM, is this normal? my dedicated server only has 2GB of ram from which normally have 1 to use. so I as soon as I deploy 3 apps I get an OOM error, I've gotten permgen OOM and a out of swamp Memory error; to fix this I upped my MaxPermGen to about a gig and resytarted the server to get back some swamp space. so I tried deploying smaller older apps ( about 15MB) and they take up waay less memory.  If I have 1 GB of ram I want to be able to fit more apps into my webserver without getting any OOM Errors.

now I found [this stack overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855758/large-portlet-war-takes-up-memory-causing-performance-issues), Can that be applied to my case? and if so, which are the common folders in the tomcat server? anyone done this before or have a different more effective, not so complicated approach?

Any ideas, and or commets are more than appreciated. Thanks!

Myy

Comment: Are you using any JVM parameters to size the heap?  You don't need maxpermgen at 1gb unless you have a really high usage of static data, string literals and class meta-data.

Comment: these are the JVM parameters I'm using -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

Comment: Try replacing -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m with -Xmx1024m

Answer (score 5):

> I deploy these war files. the webApp is about 35MB in size ( it has a lot of jars and such)

Only the files you use take up any memory. Deleting classes you don't use will save you disk space but not memory.

> but when I deploy it to my tomcat webserver, I can see it takes about 300MB of RAM, is this normal?

If you have 300 Mb free in your server it will use it all. If you have 3 GB free it might use all that too.  You need to see how much is used after using the server in a realistic way and performing a Full GC.

> If I have 1 GB of ram I want to be able to fit more apps into my webserver without getting any OOM Errors.

You need to determine how much memory each application really needs. Or you need to buy more memory as 1 GB costs about $20. (I assume its a hosted solution where memory costs much more ;)

Comment: yeah it's a virual solucion, so I'll have to pay more for more ram, which is fine. I just wanted to know if that was the case. I'm going to follow dcernahoschi's suggestion to find the apps memory footprint. but like you said, if I have 300MB free or 3 GB, how can I tell it to just Use "xX" ammount (i.e if the footprint is only 300MB of ram) how do I tell it to just use 300MB of ram?

Comment: You can reduce the maximum heap size until it stops working.  You can't limit an individual application without using a JVM per application.  This will slow down the application, but you will know the minimum memory it will run under.

Answer (score 3):

Normal memory usage depends on the webapp and what it its doing.  And as @Peter Lawrey says, there isn't a direct relationship between the size of the WAR file and the amount of memory used.

Yes, the approach of moving common JAR files out of the WARs and into the shared library folder will reduce memory, though it may not make a significant difference overall.  See the [Tomcat7 documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Shared_Library_Files) for the library folder name.

Classes in the shared libraries will only be loaded once for the JVM rather than once for each webapp that uses the.  However, if any of the classes has static state, you will find that the state is now shared across all webapps.  This can cause the objects / types from one webapp to be seen by another, which can cause problems.

> If I have 1 GB of ram I want to be able to fit more apps into my webserver without getting any OOM Errors.

Well Java does tend to be memory hungry, and realistically there is a limit to what you can do with a given amount of memory (and effort).  At the end of the day, I suspect you will need to revise your expectations downwards ... or pay for a virtual with more memory.

---

Before going down this path, I'd recommend you use a Java memory profiler to see if there is something about your webapps design and implementation that makes them use a lot of memory.

Answer (score 3):

The size of your war file does not determine how much memory your application consumes. Also, if you manage to start 5 applications in your tomcat it doesn't mean they will still run after, let's say 3 weeks.

For this you need to load test each of your application separately to determine it's memory foot print (how much memory it needs in the long run).

For this you need to:

- estimate the **maximum** number of concurrent users that will use your application
- assign to every user a test use case. For example: you might have max 100 concurrent users with 10 registering, 10 searching for some stuff, 10 entering some data, etc.
- use a tool like [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) to write/record tests for every use case
- use a java memory profiler to monitor the memory usage, garbage collection, etc. during load testing

After running your load generators for a while, the used memory should stabilize somewhere: 1GB, 1.5GB, etc. That's your memory footprint. You need to make sure that your hardware provides this much memory.

If is not stabilizing then you have memory leaks and you'll eventually get an `OutOfMemoryError`. But that's another topic.

You will try various jvm memory configurations and also pay attention to the performance of your application: TPS number. It's provided by the above tools.

I've just scratched the tip of the iceberg, load and performance testing is a dense topic.